# Django-nonrel broke after installing new version of Google App Engine SDK

Tags: python, google-app-engine, django-nonrel

I had GAE 1.4 installed in my local UBUNTU system and everything was working fine. Only warning I was getting at that time was something like "You are using old GAE SDK 1.4." So, to get rid of that I have done following things:

1. I removed old version of GAE and installed GAE 1.7. Along with that I have
   also changed my djangoappengine folder with latest version.
2. I have copied new version of GAE to /usr/local directory since my ~/bashrc file PATH variable pointing to GAE to this directory.

Now, I am getting error

`django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'djangoappengine.db' isn't an available database backend.
    Try using django.db.backends.XXX, where XXX is one of:
    'dummy', 'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'sqlite3'
Error was: No module named utils`

I don't think there is any problem of directory structure since earlier it was running fine.

Does anyone has any idea ?

Your help will be highly appreciated.

-Sunil

.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I changed the google app engine path in /.bashrc file and restarted the system. It solved the issue. I think since I was not restarting the system after .bashrc changes, hence it was creating problem.

Answer (score 1):

Did you update djangoappengine without updating django-nonrel and djangotoolbox?

While I haven't upgraded to GAE 1.7.4 yet, I'm running 1.7.2 with no problems.  I suspect your problem is not related to the GAE SDK but rather your django-nonrel installation has mismatching pieces.

Comment: :thank you for your answer. Yes, I have updated the django-nonrel and djangotoolbox after posting this question.